# Confirmation Window AFTER the method behind a button is called

Tags: jsp, jsf

Basically, I have a program that after I click a button a PDF of a data table is created. And what I would like to do is have a confirmation window pop up and say "Your PDF is ready to view", with maybe an "Ok" button. I know how to create a confirmation BEFORE the program is called, the normal "Are you sure?" confirms, but I'm looking to create one after it has ran.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my java method being used:

```
public String doEmailReportAction(){
    ILSA06 ilsa06 = new ILSA06();
    ilsa06.setKEY(getUser().getKey());
    ilsa06.setINWAGT(getAgent().getWritingAgentNumber());
    ilsa06.setINLANG(getLocale().getLanguageCode());
    ilsa06.setOBMSG("");
    ilsa06.setOBERR("");
    ilsa06.setOBPATH("");
    ilsa06.invoke();
    if (ilsa06.getOBERR().equals("1")) {
    getErrorMessages().setErrorMessage(ilsa06.getOBMSG());
    return "";
    } 
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot have that pdf program itself make the confirmation, consider having the button call another function in the middle, which calls the function to create the pdf and then makes the confirmation if it was successful.

It's hard to get more technically specific without additional information.

Comment: Well the program that is called is an RPG program, which is called from the java side.